# Low light/night vision camera

Tags: camera, low-cost

I've been working on a project that requires a camera that can record low-light and nighttime video. A few months ago, I bought a night-vision camera using infrared light [camera link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08RHZ5BJM), and I am disappointed because it doesn't work outdoors and I need a camera able to see 10-ish meters on a plain, but it was good enough for indoor testing. Now, I need a camera that can fulfill my conditions, can be connected with a USB-A cable or MIPI connector, and is under $100. The camera must also work during the day.